# django-allauth custom signup form throws an error in admin page while adding a new user. 'CustomUserForm' object has no attribute 'instance'

Tags: django, django-allauth

Trying to add a new user to the "general_user" group. since I am utilising `custom user model` and `django-allauth` I created custom registration form, inheriting allauth `SignupForm`.
it works fine in the web page, but not in the admin page. every time trying to click +add Customuser, it shows below error.

[image]

what should I check for this?

#### forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class RegistrationForm(SignupForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        max_length=60, 
        help_text='Required, Enter avalid Email address.'
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2']
    
    def custom_signup(self, request, user):
        custom_form = self #use local signup()
        if hasattr(custom_form, 'signup') and callable(custom_form.signup):
            custom_form.signup(request, user)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        general_user_group = Group.objects.get(name='general_user')
        user.groups.add(general_user_group)
        user.save()
        return user
```

#### admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from .forms import CustomUserChangeForm, RegistrationForm

CustomUser = get_user_model()

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    add_form = RegistrationForm
    model = CustomUser
    
    list_display = ('email', 'username', 'is_staff',)
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_active',)
    search_fields = ('email', 'username',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    readonly_fields = ('date_joined', 'last_login')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password',)}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('username', )}),
        ('Permissions', {
            'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions',),
        }),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined',)}),
    )
    
    # for Creating user form
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2',),
        }),
    )
    
    
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)
    
    
admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

#### settings.py

```py
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'accounts.forms.RegistrationForm'}
```

docker,
django 3.15,
python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

According to allauth docs, it seems that it's technically not working base on the fact that allauth is not applied to Django Admin.
[image]

Comment: were you able to solve this?  I'm having the same issue even though I added 
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
admin.site.login = login_required(admin.site.login)
To the required admin.py